# c# WPF get value from a List<> that is binded to a class object

Tags: c#, wpf, list

How to get value from a list that is binded to a class object?
I have a class and a List of that class. im adding to list like this

```
private void loadAccountBalance(string total, string amount, string transaction, string date)
    {
        accountBalance_lst.Add(new accountBalanace_cls()
        {
            accountBalanceTotal = total,
            accountBalanceAmount = amount,
            accountBalanceTransaction = transaction,
            accountBalanceDate = date
        });
        accountsBalance_grd.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

this is my class

```
     public class accountBalanace_cls
    {
        public string accountBalanceTotal { get; set; }
        public string accountBalanceAmount { get; set; }
        public string accountBalanceTransaction { get; set; }
        public string accountBalanceDate { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my declaration of List

```
      List<object> accountBalance_lst = new List<object>();
```

What I want to do is something like this I hope you'll understand what i'm trying to accomplish here

```
      int total = accountBalance_lst[1].AccountBalanceTotal;
```

Comment: why taged and titled **wpf**? I did not see anything of wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `accountBalance_lst` is of type `List<object>` it doesn't contains definition for `AccountBalanceTotal`. if doesn't have any specific reason for `List<object>` then make it as `List<accountBalanace_cls>` instead. Or else you can do some casting like the following:

```
  int total = ((accountBalanace_cls)accountBalance_lst[1]).AccountBalanceTotal;
```

Comment: Thanks this is what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but instead of doing this:

```
List<object> accountBalance_lst = new List<object>();
```

Why not do this:

```
var accountBalance_lst = new List<accountBalance_cls>();
```

So that you can do you can use the list objects like you wanted:

```
int total = accountBalance_lst[1].AccountBalanceTotal;
```